# Validate XML Element Attribute value using XSD

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xsd

I have following XML Element. 
I need to validate whether **Parameter** Attribute is holding only Y or N in following XML element

```
<Test Script="abc.sh" Parameter="Y"/>
               **OR**
<Test Script="abc.sh" Parameter="N"/>
```

**My XSD is :**

```
    <xs:element name="Test" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Script" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Parameter" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>                    
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Currently this XSD is not validating whether Parameter is holding **Y** or **N**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define an `attribute` with a `simpleType` representing a `restriction` in order to enforce the attribute value being member of a defined set of values.

Imagine you have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Test Script="path/to/script" Parameter="Y" xmlns="http://www.example.org" />
```

You can enforce that they `type` attribute has a value of `foo` or `bar` using this xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org"
  targetNamespace="http://www.example.org"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
>
    <xsd:element name="Test">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="Script" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        <!-- the following has no type attribute. It's type is 
             defined in the simpleType child -->
        <xsd:attribute name="Parameter" use="optional">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <!-- define a set of xsd:strings
                 as possible values -->
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:enumeration value="Y"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value="N"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I used <xs:attribute> ; you have given as <xsd:attribute> 
what is the difference ?

Comment: @logan Just personal preference. You can replace my `xsd` by your `xs` if you want. Which prefix you are using is the defined in `xmlns:xsd=..` or `xmlns:xs` in the head of the schema

Comment: Now I am using xs only but it says org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "xsd" for element "xsd:simpleType" is not bound.

Comment: If you exactly copy my example it will work.. have tested it (you may try it here) http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.UtkY-_gWWpo

Comment: should i add elementFormDefault="qualified"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified" ?

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case. Keep the value you had before, or just drop it (to have the default).. If it complains still because that `xsd|xs` naming issue, make sure you are using consequently just one of them.

Comment: My solution should work. The only difference is that it uses xs namespace prefix which is preferred over xsd which by itself has a different meaning xml schema

Comment: The error message for invalid Parameter says "Reason: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'YY' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[Y, N]'. " Is it not possible to display the XML Attribute name in the error message ?

Comment: @IndoKnight Almost :) You need `<attribute type="xs:yesno" ...`

Comment: Yes, spotted well, updated. However, I like your elaborate solution :)

Comment: @hek2mgl : The error message for invalid Parameter says "Reason: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'YY' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[Y, N]'. " Is it not possible to display the XML Attribute name in the error message ?

Comment: This depends on your validator, I'm using `xmllint` and it says: ` Element '{http://www.example.org}Test', attribute 'Parameter': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'foo' is not an element of the set {'Y', 'N'}.`

Comment: is xmllint a Java API ?

Comment: no it's code in c++ and is part of the [libxml2 distribution](http://www.xmlsoft.org/)

Answer (score 3):

You have to define your Parameter attribute like this

```
      <xs:simpleType name="yesno">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="Y" />
                <xs:enumeration value="N" />
            </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>



      <xs:attribute name="Parameter" type="xs:yesno" use="optional"/>
```

Comment: The error message for invalid Parameter says "Reason: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'YY' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[Y, N]'. " Is it not possible to display the XML Attribute name in the error message ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are parsing your xml document. You may want to check the API documentation (if parsing programmatically) or user guide(if using any tool).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<xs:element name="Test" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="Script">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:enumeration value="abc.sh">
                                        </xs:enumeration>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                              <xs:attribute name="Parameter">
                                 <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:pattern value="Y|N" >
                                        </xs:pattern>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                 </xs:simpleType>    
                              </xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```